# how to access partitions made in windows in ubuntu installed in dual boot alongside windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have installed ubuntu on my laptop alongside my windows 10(that i use primarily).

when ubuntu was installed, I noticed that grub was not booting into windows but was booting in ubuntu.

so i had to manually select windows boot loader by pressing f12 wile booting.

but when i booted into ubuntu i noticed that windows partitions were showing but were not accessible.

I want to use ubuntu for my college purposes so i will have to transfer many files between windows and ubuntu.

even if i could access one partition from my hdd is enough.

i didnt get any solution on the internet so far so i havent tried anything.

if you know what to do please help.

Comment: What exactly is your question, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: And what do you mean by "windows partitions were showing but were not accessible"?

Comment: what is error or warning when you try to access windows partitions?? Also please provide a screen-shot of your disk status.

Comment: @Pilot6 I think his problem is the unclean file system error caused by Windows Fast Boot

Comment: @Arun Most likely https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @Pilot6 seems so

Comment: @Kavin Mayekar - If I understand the essence of your question correctly, you have disk partitions that you can access in Windows but not in Linux.  Is this the problem?  One person evidently does not agree with my interpretation of your question and has downvoted my answer.  I don't believe that this action is justified - if - your question is what I believe.  The solution proposed works admirably on my own computer and I can easily read and write files on "Drive D:" in Windows which shows up as /media/DataDisk in Linux!

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you just have to mount the "Windows" partitions that you can't immediately access in Linux.  You can use a mount command or edit the file system table to make the mount process automatic.  See, for example, https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/mounting-disks-automatically/

Answer (score 0):

Let me first say that if your goal is to easily and reliably share files between Windows and Ubuntu, then the best way is to create a new NTFS partition on your hard disk to share files, rather than trying to mount your Windows C: partition and reading/writing to that.

However, if you *must* read/write to your Windows C: partition from Ubuntu, then you must prepare Windows in the following way:

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, its probably because Ubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this...

## in Windows

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C: